# Can we create a tag for AGA cooking?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think it would be useful to have a tag relating to AGA cookers, and possibly another one relating to AIMS (Aga Intelligent Management System).

Due to my reputation I can't suggest/create one myself.

Let me know your thoughts.

**Edit:**

After this question being marked as a duplicate, I want to mention that I only followed the advice from [this Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work) about tag creation.

The answer quotes:

*As an alternative, you can request creating a tag by starting a new meta discussion. This gives other people the opportunity to discuss if a new tag is needed.*

Since I thought this question was adequate for an open discussion, I thought it would be appropriate to post in on meta site.

Comment: I think Aaronut misunderstood your intent, or maybe forgot that new users cannot create a proposed edit with a tag which does not exist in the system yet. Reopening.

Comment: Oh, now I see the new answer Aaronut gave to the repurposed FAQ question. It is a very good answer, and it makes sense to follow the rules he outlines there: essentially, make the "approved way" to be to post the request not on meta, but on the relevant question which needs the tag. Under these rules, your question here is indeed obsolete, and the answers Jefromi and I posted basically say the same thing: show us a question which needs the tag, and we will add it there. From this point of view, it is indeed reasonable to close this q as a duplicate of the more general one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a question that either of these tags should be applied to, just ask for the tag to be added to it. Not having the tag shouldn't stop you (or anyone else) from posting such a question!

(And if there are no questions about AGA cookers, I guess we don't need the tag.)

Comment: Please *don't* ask for a tag to be added to a question. Suggest a tag edit. If it's useful, it'll be accepted, and if not, then it won't. I don't think I've *ever* seen another question about an AGA cooker, and low-frequency tags get pruned automatically anyway, so there's not much sense in talking about this until we have at least a few of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a tag independently of a question. You will have to ask a relevant question first, and then you can ask somebody to edit its tags. When a person with sufficient reputation adds a tag which has never been used before, it will get created automatically.

In principle, I agree with Jefromi's "if there are no questions about AGA cookers, I guess we don't need the tag"  Indeed, in most cases, creating a new tag which applies to a single question and cannot be retroactively applied to existing questions is usually an indication that it is way too specific to be of any use (e.g. suppose somebody created the tag of "peeling-peaches-for-jam"). This is why we don't use this process (requesting a tag on meta) very frequently.

But in this case, I think that creating your tag is reasonable. It defines a very specific category which is both clearly delineated and not too specific. The reason it has not come up before is that these cookers are so unusual that nobody has yet asked a question about them. If you ask the first question, we can label it with the tag.